# Using class methods to draw on HTML5 Canvas: scope problems (JS, ES6)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, es6-class

I am having some trouble wrapping my head around some scope problems. I am using a class method to draw a square on the canvas and would like to move it around using another class method, but it seems I can't pass along the context...

```
class User {
  constructor(user, x, y, ctx) {
    for (let metric in user) { this[metric] = user[metric]; }
    this.initialX = x;
    this.initialY = y;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.draw(this.initialX, this.initialY, this.ctx);
   }

  draw(x, y, ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,20,20);
  }

  move(e) {
    //// stuff about motion goes here
     console.log(e.key, this.ctx); //// can't access `ctx` - the user key shows up in the console but the context is nowhere to be seen
     //// eventually this needs to be draw(x, y, ctx) that's passed back up to the draw function
  }

}
```

The context is passed into the User class further down in the code as shown [in this pen](http://codepen.io/jlr7245/pen/mOQzEJ) but as far as I can tell the way it's being passed to the User class isn't a problem, it's the way I'm accessing it in the move function.

I did also try defining a variable for the context in the constructor function independent of `this` but that wasn't successful either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must bind your method. [ES6 classes doesn't do that automatically.](http://www.ian-thomas.net/autobinding-react-and-es6-classes/)

In your constructor try to add this line:

```
this.move = this.move.bind(this);
```

Comment: Oh great, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting four arguments `(e, x, y, ctx)` into your event listener function but the listener will receive [only one argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener), the event.

Your have to explicitly pass all the arguments to your handler in order to use them or figure out another way to access them.